# Javascript objects understand a variable as string instead of a variable

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects

I have two questions about javascript and objects. The first one is:

I have this part of code:

```
  const handleAnotherStep = () => {
    let procedures = 
      {key:
        {
          stepType: {
            stepCode: {
              language: stepText,
              timeout,
              nextInstruction,
            }
          }
        }
      }
    setProcedures(procedures)
    console.log(procedures)
  }
```

The key, stepType, stepCode, language, stepText, timeout and nextInstruction are in a useState(). The problem is: the console.log of this is:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

But it should be like this :

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

You see? Instead of s'tepType', what should be written was the content of the stepType variable. Instead of the 'Key' the content of the key should be there. You get my point? Please, help me, I'm struggling in this and I'm newbie with JS. The nextInstruction and timeout are working just fine. I thin the javascript thinks the key, stepType, stepCode and language are a string, instead of a variable.

Comment: "Instead of the 'Key' the content of the key should be there. You get my point?" No, because your point is wrong. A key is a key. There is no variable replacement that occurs there.

Comment: `key`, `stepType`, `stepKey`, these are all _keys_ of an object. It's not clear how you want them to be _variables_. Also, how are you generating the output that you use in your images?

Comment: The images that are in the right format, I did by hand, on firebase. Now, I want to allow the users to do it. With the variables I'm doing like this `case 'ProcedureCode':
        let k = e.target.value
        setKey(k)
        return` The user writes it, and I set in a useState()

Comment: @rmlan The key is a const [key, setKey] = useState(). When the user writes in the input text, I setKey with what he wrote. Let's say, 'DOF001'. What I want the object to have is, instead of the word 'KEY', I want the  'DOF001' wrote there.

Comment: You need [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Syntax).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `[var]` to get the value of a variable as the key and for the value, you can give the variable itself.

```
  const handleAnotherStep = () => {
    let procedures = 
      {[key]:
        {
          [stepType]: {
            [stepCode]: {
              [language]: stepText,
              timeout,
              nextInstruction,
            }
          }
        }
      }
    setProcedures(procedures)
    console.log(procedures)
  }
```

And for your second question to add a method to handle adding of steps you need not check because you just want to add an object so I think you can simply give,

```js
  const handleAnotherStep = () => {
    let newProcedures = 
      {[key]:
        {
          [stepType]: {
            [stepCode]: {
              [language]: stepText,
              timeout,
              nextInstruction,
            }
          }
        }
      }
    setProcedures({...prevProcedures, ...newProcedures})
    console.log(procedures)
  }
```

Note: Also immediately logging the procedure after setting the state will not give the correct value.

Comment: Yeah, it worked. Thank you. Now, could you help me with the second question ?